# Scaling nested RichText widgets for accessibility

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm wrestling with how `RichText` handles nested spans that contain other `RichText` instances. It works fine as long as the user doesn't change the phone's default font size. But if they have changed the display font size, things start going awry.

Consider the case where I'm parsing some HTML that looks like:

```
<underline><italic><bold>xxxxx</bold></italic></underline>
```

Conceptually this can be modelled as a `TextSpan` inside a `TextSpan` inside a `TextSpan`, so I might have some contrived code that looks like:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final inputText = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
    final initialSpan = TextSpan(text: inputText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black));

    final boldText = _buildStyledElement(context, initialSpan, Style.bold);
    final boldItalised = _buildStyledElement(context, WidgetSpan(child: boldText), Style.italic);
    final boldItalisedUnderlined = _buildStyledElement(context, WidgetSpan(child: boldItalised), Style.underline);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(inputText), // a simple baseline to compare
          boldText,
          boldItalised,
          boldItalisedUnderlined,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  RichText _buildStyledElement(BuildContext context, InlineSpan span, Style style) {
    // note we're not applying the style because it isn't important... the style parameter
    // is just a means of wrapping our heads around a real-world example of nesting
    return RichText(text: span);
  }
}
```

As you can see on the left, it looks great with normal font size but on the right, the three `RichText` cases don't scale when you adjust the phone's fonts size.

[image: No scaling]

That's easy to explain though... because the default scaling factor for a `RichText` is `1.0` so there's no scaling. Let's fix that by changing the creation code to look like:

```
return RichText(text: span, textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor);
```

As you can see below, the normal font still looks good, but woah... things scale up real quickly due to the `RichText` nesting (I'm assuming it is applying the scale factor onto already scaled children).

[image: Scaling based on device]

Now, one thing I've found is that if I allow all the `RichText` widgets to be created using a scale factor of `1.0`, and then wrap the outermost in a `RichText` that is using the device's scale factor, it /almost/ works. For example, remove the scaling in `_buildStyledElement` and add this row into the main `Column` widget:

```
RichText(text: WidgetSpan(child: boldItalisedUnderlined), textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor),
```

As you can see, things look good at the normal font size and actually scale to the correct size for large fonts. However, the wrapping is now broken.

[image: Just scaling the outer widget]

I'm assuming that this is because the size that is calculated by the child `RichText` widgets (because they are using a scale factor of `1.0`) doesn't marry up with the total calculated space when using the media query's scale factor.

Sooo... I guess my question is whether there is a way to actually get this to work properly with nested `RichText` instances. I know that for this specific example there may be some other options... but I'm talking about the general case where `RichText` widgets embed other `RichText` widgets.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: FWIW, I just raised a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59316

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of not having a definite solution there's a workaround that I found particularly useful for my purpose:

You need to set the text scale factor for the Html Widget fixed to 1, and choose a default font size for your average text on the HTML the multiply it to the current scale factor of the screen (not the fixed manually).

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  ExampleWidget({this.data});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double scaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
    int standardFontSize = 14;
    int h3FontSize = 18;
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData(textScaleFactor: 1),
      child: Html(
        data: data,
        style: {
          'body': Style(fontSize: FontSize(standardFontSize * scaleFactor)),
          'h3': Style(fontSize: FontSize(h3FontSize * scaleFactor))
          // other header fonts...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The downside is needing to manually implement every time you need a new font size but it might solve an urgent problem.

Comment: I can see how this might resolve the scaling problem... does your text wrap properly in this case? All of my investigations have found that setting the innermost scale factors to 1.0 and then wrapping in a single (correct) MediaQuery scale factor will result in a) correctly scaled text, but b) text that doesn't wrap at the correct boundary.  Of course, I haven't been testing changing the font size specifically... I've only been looking at manipulating the textScaleFactor. Your technique definitely looks like a pretty good workaround

Comment: Yes, the wrap work as expected since the text boundaries don't outgrow the screen anymore.